# Navigation li alignment

Tags: css, alignment, html-lists

I am having an issue were I cannot get my 'li' width correct.  I have the design I am working off and they look to be about `20px` apart to the right with `display:inline-block` but I cannot seem to get the numbers correct. [JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/JnVMk/)

**HTML:**

```
<div class="footer">
            <nav>
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="#">Terms of Use</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Site Map</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Privacy Policy</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Help</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Company</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
                </ul>    
            </nav>

            </div>​
```

**CSS:**

```
.footer nav{
    float:right;
    width:530px;
    padding:13px 0 0 0;
}
.footer nav ul{
    list-style:none;
}
.footer nav li{
    display:inline-block;
    width:80px;
    text-align:center;
}
.footer nav li a{
    text-decoration:none;
    color:#000;
}​
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want the distance between them to be fixed, you can't use fixed-width list items for contents with varying width, and you can't center the text. Just leave the width at `auto`, and set a `margin-right` of `20px` to make them that distance apart from each other.